# Regular expression to get the characters which occur after 2 or more space

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to OCR a receipt and read the line items. So after I get the line items I wanted to get the price of the item with the currency symbol.

```
CHOC. ORANGE   x           £1.00
```

I was trying to break the text with pound sign, but some times OCR mistake the pound to some other characters.

So is there a way in regex to read the characters from the end of the line and stop when it encounters a space of more that 3 ? Or do I have to write a custom algorithm ?

I was trying to get the last word from the end of the line, but that also fails when it encounters punctuations or space.

```
\b(\w+)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expression, you use a **Quantifier** to specify the number of occurrence of a matched pattern.  For two or more white space characters, the regex would be `\s{2,}`.

For your problem, you also need to be prepare that the pound symbol may or may not be correctly recognized.  So, I would use `|` to express the alternatives.

The following program gives an example how that can be done:

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexReceiptOcr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      String poundSymbol = Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK).getSymbol();
        String poundSymbol = "£";
        String[] inputStrings = {
                "CHOC. ORANGE    x         " + poundSymbol + "1.00"
                , "CHOC. ORANGE    x         L1.00"
        };

        String regex = "(?<description>.+)"
                + "\\s{2,}"                             // two or more white space
                + "(?<currency>"+poundSymbol+"|\\w)"    // Pound symbol may be mis-reaad
                + "(?<amount>\\d+\\.\\d{2})";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        for (String inputString : inputStrings) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
            if (m.find()) {
                String description  = m.group("description");
                String currency     = m.group("currency");
                String amountString = m.group("amount");

                System.out.format("Desciption: %s%n"
                        + "Currency: %s%n"
                        + "Amount: %s%n"
                        , description.trim()
                        , currency
                        , amountString);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output would be this:

```
Desciption: CHOC. ORANGE    x
Currency: £
Amount: 1.00
Desciption: CHOC. ORANGE    x
Currency: L
Amount: 1.00
```

Comment: Thanks , this is what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(£|\$)[0-9]+.[0-9]+
```

this will do it with no need to spaces and checking end of line
[demo](https://regex101.com/r/8VBfnQ/3)

Edit:

```
String s= "£1.00";
String currency =s.substring(0,1);
String amount=s.substring(1, s.length());
```

Comment: Thanks, As I mentioned, some times I don't get the pound symbol, instead I get euro or some other character via the OCR process. Thats why I wanted to split it after the long space.

Comment: so you can use this regex to split it after the sign, when you cross a number

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with, should allow you to find your prices whether it contains just dollars or a dollar & pennies.

```
[£$](\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

If you need more currency symbols than £ and $ just add them in the first set of brackets []

See https://regex101.com/r/JzHloV/5 for examples

If you want to match any amount after 2 or more space you can use the following:

```
 \s{2,}\W+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/f4gmSu/3 for example.

It will look for any 2 space (or more) than any symbol and then the amount and only capture the amount.